# Automatic 3 party flow

Tags: corda

I am new to Corda and have a use case where I need to do the following:

I have 3 Nodes:

BankA, BankB, BankC.

Account**A** is an account on Bank**A**, Account**B** is an account on Bank**B** and Account**C** is an account on Bank**C**

1. AccountA sends an invoice to AccountB
2. AccountB **automatically** sends the full amount of payment to AccountA
3. On receipt of the money from AccountB, AccountA **automatically** sends 20% of this payment to AccountC
4. The remaining 80% goes to AccountA.

In this simple scenario I am not concerned if AccountB has enough money to make a payment, it is a proof of concept.  The only 'manual' step is the sending of an invoice by AccoutA, the remaining steps are automatically triggered.

Is there a way to do this in Corda using Accounts and if so how ? Example code/pseudocode would be great.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to be as detailed as possible:

1. Create a state `Invoice` that has amount attribute and 3 attributes of type `AbstractParty` (i.e. accountA, accountB, and accountC).
2. Your state will have 2 commands: `Issue` and `Exit` (or `Pay`; I'll use `Pay`, you can use any name of course).
3. Create a flow that creates an `Invoice` state (i.e. `Issue` command).
4. Your proof of concept is about sending the amounts from accountA to accountB to accountC, but what proves that this amount distribution actually happened? It can be proved if all 3 accounts signed your transaction, more on that below.
5. Your `Invoice` state will have a contract (to validate the different commands), for the `Pay` command you must check that all 3 accounts are required signers.
6. Now create the pay invoice flow which will be 2 parts (initiator and responder).
7. The initiator will create a transaction, the input is the `Invoice` state, the required signers are the 3 accounts, there is no output (meaning the invoice is paid and now it's off-ledger).
8. Then the flow will use the `sendAndReceive` function to send the invoice state to NodeB.
9. Now inside the responder flow **which is installed on NodeB**, NodeB can do many checks, for example NodeB will check that accountB (which it extracts from the received `Invoice`) is hosted on it, if not; it will throw an error.
10. You said you don't care about payment for now, so you can send back to NodeA an object of type `Double` with amount that equals to the amount in the received invoice (remember that we used `sendAndReceive` in the initator so NodeA is waiting for a `send` from the responder; otherwise the flow will be stuck). If you want to see an example of using the tokens SDK to pay for a state; have a look here: https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/master/docs/DvPTutorial.md, in your case instead of a token that represents a House, you'll have a normal state (i.e. `Invoice extends LinearState` or `ContractState`).
11. Now back to the initiator, the initiator just received the amount from NodeB; it will first check that the received amount equals to the invoice amount
12. Now it will send 20% to NodeC: you can use `send` to send the invoice and an object of type `Double` to represent the amount (the 20%).
13. As you can see, there is lot of juggling between the initiator and responder for each `receive` from the initiator, a `send` from the responder must exist (btw, `CollectSignaturesFlow` which you call inside the initiator has a `receive`, which you fulfill by calling `SignTransactionFlow` -which has a `send`- in the responder).
14. Now inside the responder **that is installed inside NodeC**, it will receive the `Double`; you can do some validation (e.g. accountC is hosted on NodeC, for example validate that the amount of object `Double` equals to 20% of the received invoice amount).
15. Now back to the initiator, it will call the `CollectSignaturesFlow` to collect signature of accountB from NodeB, and signature of accountC form NodeC.
16. Inside responder of NodeB call `SignTransactionFlow`.
17. Inside responder of NodeC call `SignTransactionFlow`.
18. Inside the initiator call the finality flow.
19. Inside the responders call the receive finality flow.

Notice how I mentioned that there are 2 responders (one installed on NodeB and one on NodeC), that's because NodeB has a different response logic from NodeC. Having 2 responders is a bit of an advanced topic; so instead just create one responder flow and inside of it check the party of the flow session, if it's PartyB; then do PartyB logic, otherwise do PartyC logic.
Below is the pseudo code of the above steps:

```
// Notice the sequence of the numbers; that's how the juggeling is happening

// Initiator (NodeA)
1. Choose notary
2. Create empty transaction
3. Set input (Invoice), required signers (the 3 accounts), command (Pay)
4. Validate tx (state contract is called)
5. Send invoice to PartyB 
9. Receive double
10. Validate that Double.amount = 100% invoice.amount
11. Send invoice and Double(20 %) to NodeC
14. Sign transaction with NodeA key and accountA key (node A must sign with its key
 because it initiated the flow)
15. Call CollectSignaturesFlow
16. Call Finality flow


// Responder
If (session.party = PartyB)
    6. Receive invoice
    7. Validate that accountB is hosted on NodeB
    8. Send  new Double(100% invoice amount)
    16. Call SignTransactionFlow
    17. Call receive finality flow
// PartyC
else
    12. Receive invoice and Double
    13. Validate accountC is hosted here and Double.amount == 20%
    16. Call SignTransactionFlow
    17. Call receive finality flow
```